# jQuery.url plugin not working from within click handler function

Tags: jquery, url, jquery-plugins, click

I'm trying to use the jQuery.url plugin (http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_url_parser/) to grab a specific parameter from the query string of a url of an anchor which has just been clicked on, like so:

HTML:

```
<a class="clickonme" href="http://www.example.com/my/url/params?myparam=ABC123">Link text</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var myParam = '';
$("a.clickonme").click(function() {
    myParam = jQuery.url.setUrl($(this).attr('href')).param('myparam');
            console.log('myParam: '+myParam);
    return false;
});
```

What I'm expecting to see is 'myParam: ABC123' in FireBug's console, but instead I get the error: "jQuery.url is undefined".

I've tested whether my script can see the url plugin by running the following code:

```
    var myURL = 'http://www.example.com/my/url/params?myparam=ABC123';
var myParam = jQuery.url.setUrl(myURL).param('myparam');
$("a.clickonme").click(function() {
    console.log('myParam: '+myParam);
    return false;
});
```

When I run this, the jQuery.url plugin works fine (there are no JavaScript errors in the console and my desired result 'myParam: ABC123' is returned).

So basically, when I try to use the jQuery.url plugin inside a click handler, the script appears to not know it exists, but if I move it outside the click handler, it works as normal.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You are explicitly defining `myURL` in the second example. Have you tried doing that in the first example? Also, I dont believe that you need the single quotes around `myparam` in your call to `.param()`

Comment: The reason I'm explicitly defining myURL
in the second example is because $(this).attr('href') doesn't refer to the href of the link that has just been clicked outside of the click handler. 

That's why I want to use the jQuery.url plugin inside the click handler, so I can use $(this).attr('href') to get the clicked-on URL.

Also, I've checked the jQuery.url documentation and shows quotes are used around myparam in the call to .param()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.clickonme").click(function() {
        myParam = jQuery.url.setUrl($(this).attr('href')).param('myparam');
        console.log('myParam: '+myParam);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The only way I could replicate your bug was to add/remove the document ready state.